# How to add an HTML-class to an ActiveAdmin index table

Tags: activeadmin

For some custom (ordering) Javascript, I'd like to add a class, "sortable" to the table in an `ActiveAdmin`-resource.

The default generated HTML is:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" paginator="true" class="index_table index" id="products">
```

I'd like to add a class:

```
<table ... class="index_table index sortable" ...>
```

Or, if that is not possible, a "data-sortable" property. Like so:

```
<table ... data-sortable="products">
```

I've tried to pass in some HTML-ish hashes, but they are not picked up:

```
index(:class => "sortable") do
end

index(:html_attributes => {:class => "sortable"}) do
end
```

Reading the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activeadmin/ActiveAdmin/Views/IndexAsTable%3abuild) makes me no wiser.

How can I add custom classes or attributes to the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, index as table doesn't accept these extra options.

If you're looking to easily add drag and drop ordering  (with both simple ordering and trees) I'd recommend the [Active Admin Sortable Tree](https://github.com/nebirhos/activeadmin-sortable-tree) gem.

Otherwise you can always roll [your own index builder](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/custom-index.html)